# shuf command running every time I open a terminal - how can I turn it off?

Tags: command-line, bash

```
shuf: option requires an argument -- 'n'
Try 'shuf --help' for more information.
What manual page do you want?
shuf: option requires an argument -- 'n'
Try 'shuf --help' for more information.
What manual page do you want?
shuf: option requires an argument -- 'n'
Try 'shuf --help' for more information.
What manual page do you want?
cyber@compak:~$
```

Above is the text that appears every time I open a new terminal in my Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I turn it off. I lent my PC to somebody and they returned it in this state.

Contents of the `.bashrc` file in my home directory.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n `
man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n `
man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n `
```

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `.bashrc` file in your home directory? Looks like someone added some commands there which do not work as intended...

Comment: they kind of cant all fit here in the comment box

Comment: I believe that they want you to [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/910925/edit) your question and add the contents of your .bashrc to your question and not the comment box.

Comment: ok then, on it now.....

Comment: Strange, the last three lines of your .bashrc file look like they are trying to execute something....

Comment: If the last line(s) looked like `man \`ls /usr/bin | shuf -n 1\``, then when you opened a terminal it would pull up the man pages for three random commands.  I assume that @ByteCommander is correct:  Someone added a series of commands to your .bashrc file in an attempt to pull a prank on you, but had a typo when setting up their prank.

Comment: actually, running through my terminal history, i just found these 2 commands in order as i have labelled them 1 & 2. meaning that the person run 1 first and then 2 just after..   1: echo 'man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n `'>> ~/.bashrc   2:  cmd echo 'man `ls /usr/bin | shuf -n `'>> ~/.bashrc

Comment: @MrCyber Did you ever fix your issue?

Comment: not really. havent fixed the problem yet

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the last 3 lines from your `.bashrc` file by running the following command from a terminal command.  The command will backup your `.bashrc` as `.bashrc.bak` that can be moved back in case something goes wrong:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak; for i in $(seq 3); do sed -i '$d' ~/.bashrc; done
```

Close your terminal, then when you open a new one you should not see that message anymore.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, your problem is the `shuf` command that someone put in your ~/.bashrc file. You can easily remove all of the offending lines from the config file you provided by opening a terminal and running

```
grep -v "shuf" ~/.bashrc | tee ~/.bashrc
```

That should remove all lines containing `shuf` from your .bashrc file.